# A Basic Question E-views

Tags: statistics, optimization, economics, math-software, time-series

I ask a question about E-views. Is the P-value in the picture less than 0.05 or greater than 0.05? I'm confused because of the presence of the sign '<' in front of 0.10. Please help mee. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-value is somewhere in $[0,0.10)$. It is not necessarily less than $0.05$